# CakePHP folders in webroot get redirected to app/webroot/folder

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

**In CakePHP you can access files in webroot via *domain/file***

For example the favicon.ico file located at *app/webroot/favicon.ico* can be accessed from

> example.com/favicon.ico

**Directories on the other hand seem to have a gotcha.**

If I have a directory called **blog** in the app/webroot/, then as long as I try to access it like:

> example.com/blog/

Then it works as expected. However if I try to access it without the trailing slash:

> example.com/blog

Then it gets redirected to:

> example.com/**app/webroot**/blog/

This is undesired. I woult rather `.com/folder` get redirected to `.com/folder/` instead of `.com/app/webroot/folder/`

Is there a way to set this up?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed wordpress blog and cakephp  in document root, you need to replace .htaccess file script with below script:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/YOUR_WORDPRESS_DIR.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/YOUR_WORDPRESS_DIR.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i am using cakephp 2.3.x and its working fine for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Router::Connect for blog to redirect directly to the good page? Of course this is not an automatic routine but it mighthelp you.

More info : http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration

I suppose there might be a parameter in the config core files, have you already had a look there?

Comment: The folders I am referring to are not a part of the cake framework for example a WordPress blog. Thats why they are in webroot in the first place. So I don't think I would want to use `Router:Connect`, a part of the cake framework, to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the instructions [here](http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-redirect-appwebrootblog-into-blog-wordpress-cakephp/)